# Where do I start with developing a Silverlight app using Windows Workflow Foundation?

Tags: silverlight, workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

We are starting out with the development of a Silverlight app that will make use of Windows Workflow Foundation (WF4). Our workflows are long-running. We plan to use the tracking and persistence functionality of WF. We will probably need to also store data related to each workflow instance in another DB (I suspect running reporting against the workflow persistence store would be tricky). Our workflows may change with time so we would probably also need some strategy to implement versioning on them.

So specifically, are there any resources you can point me to or direction you can give me on where to start, taking into account that we need to implement tracking, persistence and versioning of workflows?

Comment: I'm sorry, this isn't an acceptable question here.  Before you get closed as *not a real question* I'd suggest you edit this to ask a **single** question that can be reasonably answered.

Comment: Ok, agreed. Really just wanted to give an overview of what we're trying to accomplish (including all the factors we need to take into account). I edited the question.

Comment: So, the question was revised such that I'm not sure my answer applies.  It really sounds like your question is purely about WWF, not Silverlight at all?  Is that correct?

Comment: Be sure to see my blog post on [Using Workflow Services and Silverlight Together](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/05/18/using-workflow-services-and-silverlight-together.aspx) for some useful tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question, I'm assuming that you already have experience with WWF and are really just asking about how it interacts with Silverlight.  The short answer is that it would not be noticeably different from how you would implement a WWF-enabled application in traditional ASP.NET.  Remember that Silverlight is only a UI client that usually lives on top of a traditional ASP.NET web application.  Your WWF-related logic and code would live in the ASP.NET layer -- not in Silverlight at all.

So if you already know how to make a WWF-enabled application in ASP.NET, all you really need to learn is how to wire up a shiny Silverlight interface to an ASP.NET web app.  For that, you of course only need to hit up http://silverlight.net/, which you're probably already doing.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to web development and this pointed me in the right direction